# SQL SERVER UPDATE CON INNER JOIN Y NULL, TODO JUNTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, update, null

tengo que actualizar en sql server el campo [H_ESTADO_CIVIL] con el valor correspondiente según tabla ESTADO_CIVIL que  adjunto adjunto el siguiente script:

```
UPDATE [AUXILIAR1] SET [H_ESTADO_CIVIL] = [CLASE]
FROM [AUXILIAR1] 
INNER JOIN [ESTADO_CIVIL]
ON [ESTADOCIVIL] = [CLAALF]
```

[ESTADOCIVIL] char (1), null

TABLA: [ESTADO_CIVIL]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

FUNCIONA BIEN EXCEPTO CUANDO EL VALOR DE: DBO.[AUXILIAR1].[ESTADOCIVIL] = 'NULL'

RESULTADO ACTUAL: NULL
RESULTADO ESPERADO:2

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para que los registros que tienen `null` en ambas tablas formen coincidencias, simplemente incluye esa condición dentro del inner join:

```
FROM [AUXILIAR1] INNER JOIN [ESTADO_CIVIL]
              ON [AUXILIAR1].[ESTADOCIVIL] = [ESTADO_CIVIL].[CLAALF]
              OR (    [AUXILIAR1].[ESTADOCIVIL] is null
                  and [ESTADO_CIVIL].[CLAALF] is null
                 )
```

En lenguaje plano esta condición diría algo como: "forman parte del resultado aquellos registros cuyo valor sea el mismo en ambas tablas, o cuyo valor sea NULL en ambas tablas".

Otra forma de obtener el mismo resultado puede ser sustituyendo el valor `null` en cada una de las tablas por un valor especial, que no existe en la tabla. El *problema* de este método es que debes asegurarte de usar un valor que NUNCA vaya a existir en las tablas... por ejemplo, agregar un constraint `check` para asegurarte que solo pueden haber valores positivos, entonces utilizar `-1` como sustituto de `null` para comparar:

```
FROM [AUXILIAR1] INNER JOIN [ESTADO_CIVIL]
              ON coalesce([ESTADOCIVIL], -1) = coalesce([CLAALF], -1)
```

Esto deja una sentencia más corta, con un desempeño ligeramente más pobre.